# removing specific html tags in a string - javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to clean up a string of text on the server side from the output generated by a wysiwyg. and while I can fix it client side, it's best to also fix this on the server side.

```
var string = "<p>firstline</p><p>secondline</p><p>thirdline</p><p>iframe</p><p>a</p><p>df</p><p>dsf&nbsp;</p><p><br></p><p>sd</p><p>f</p><p>sdf</p><p><br></p>"

var x = string.replace("<p><br></p>", "");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8c0yh9r7/

the code should but doesn't get rid of the break within the paragraphs

why is that?

Comment: I was tempted to answer but far easier for you to delve into docs: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regex with a global flag, like:

```
 string.replace(/<p><br><\/p>/g, "");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lu2r3820/1/

When using a string only the first occurrence will be replaced.

See [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) documentation

Answer (score 2):

> doesn't get rid of the break within the paragraphs

Yes, it does… but only **once**. You have more than one paragraph containing a line break in your code.

If you want to replace it more than once, you need to use a regex and mark it as global with `g`.

```
var x = string.replace(/<p><br><\/p>/g, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

It does replace, but only the first occurrence. If you run this afterwards, you can see the second occurrence disappearing.

```
var x = x.replace("<p><br></p>", "");
```

refer to this to replace all occurrences.
[How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)